# Conditional rendering based on checkbox input in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, conditional-rendering

I'm attempting to conditionally render form elements based on user input in Vue, and it is not going well. I know how to do this using VanillaJS or jQuery, but I'm struggling to translate that knowledge into using Vue's built-in conditional directives. I'm using single-file components with the webpack template from vue-cli.

From my `<template>`:

```
<form autocomplete="off" name="loadDeets" id="loadDeets" class="loadDeets">
    <div class="form-group row">
       <label>Date</label>
       <flat-pickr v-model="date"
              :config="{dateFormat: 'l, F j'}"
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="Select date"               
                name="date"></flat-pickr>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col left">
           <label>Time</label>
           <flat-pickr v-model="time"
                :config="config"
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="Select time"               
                name="time1"></flat-pickr>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col right">
            <label>Time</label>
            <flat-pickr
                :config="config"
                class="form-control" 
                placeholder="Select time"               
                name="time2" v-show="document.getElementById('apptCheck').checked"></flat-pickr>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="apptCheck">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="apptCheck">
           Appointment?
        </label>
    </div>
 </form>
```

This breaks the page's component rendering altogether. So then I tried using v-model based on this page from the Vue documentation. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#v-model-with-Components

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group col left">
      <label>Time</label>
      <flat-pickr v-model="time"
           :config="config"
            class="form-control" 
            placeholder="Select time"               
            name="time1"></flat-pickr>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col right">
       <label>Time</label>
       <flat-pickr
           :config="config"
            class="form-control" 
            placeholder="Select time"               
            name="time2" v-show="vm.checked == true"></flat-pickr>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="checked" id="apptCheck" v-model="checked">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="apptCheck">
        Appointment?
    </label>
 </div>
```

Unfortunately, that also breaks the page.

I'm not entirely sure how to proceed from here. Am I not thinking about this correctly? Is v-if/v-show not meant to be used with input from other elements?

Comment: Lose the `vm` in `vm.checked` and just use `v-show="checked"`

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/xo8q7w9w7p

Comment: Thank you for the example, it helped me fix what would have been another struggle on Jeff's answer!

Comment: You're welcome Amanda! Feel free to keep asking questions if you have any doubts.

Comment: I do actually have one further question-- this form actually has the same fields twice (pickup and delivery) on the same page; I'm not having any issues with the other fields mirroring input; they each recognize a unique instance of the `v-model` (or such is my understanding, at least). But the checkboxes do not; if one is checked, the other is checked, and then they force the related inputs to mirror one another. Is this because it's not a component itself?

Comment: Are you using the same data property for both checkboxes? If that's the case, `v-model` is pointing to the same property `checked` when you should have two different ones, one for each checkbox. For example, `data() { return { pickupChecked: false, deliveryChecked: false } }`. One should have `v-model="pickupChecked"` and the other `v-model="deliveryChecked"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your second example is the correct way to do this, you should never need to access an element by ID in Vue.  You have access to all the variables in your component, so you don't need `vm.`, just `v-show="checked"`:

```
   <flat-pickr
       :config="config"
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="Select time"               
        name="time2" v-show="checked"></flat-pickr>
```

Make sure you instantiate `checked` in your data function as well. Rather than put `value="checked"` on that element to start, you can set it equal to `true` in your starting data and `v-model="checked"` will automatically check it.

Comment: Is there an easy way to do this, but instead of hiding the button, grey it out and make it unclickable? Seems like something simple but I'm having trouble finding it.

Comment: @BigGuy `<button :disabled="checked">` would be disabled if the `checked` variable is true.